# Can't get text in a "readonly" input element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I am making a web-automation script that retrieves text that appears after clicking a button, however the text is inside an input element like:

```
<input type="TEXT" autocomplete="off" class="DFGUISLE Readonly1" name="Readonly1" id="Readonly1" maxlength="150" readonly="" tabindex="-1" style="dir:ltr;   position:absolute; left:276; top:552; width:899; height:24;  ">
```

[image: Screenshot of the input element]

Problem is, when I try:

```
output_fields = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
for output_field in output_fields:
    print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].value", output_field))
    >> (blank)
    print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText", output_field))
    >> (blank)
    print(output_field.get_attribute('value').encode('utf-8'))
    >> b''
    print(output_field.get_attribute('innerText').encode('utf-8'))
    >> b''
```

I get blank outputs. Any clue on how to get the text from these input elements? Like, in this case, I am looking for the
`Merk en type : AUDI`

EDIT 1:

I also noticed that in Network Logger, after I click "Opvragen", the text can be seen from a response as follows:

```
parent.instanciate(new Array('EntryField','1689296692','CMV_WD_PBL01_CONSULT_STATUS','Readonly1',"Merk en type : AUDI")).setAttributes(false,'','','none','noop',null,null);
```

EDIT 2:

If you would like to try,
Link: [mobilit.fgov.be/WebdivPub/wmvpstv1](https://mobilit.fgov.be/WebdivPub/wmvpstv1) and put `WAUZZZ8VXE1009546` into `Chassisnummer` then press `Opvragen`

Comment: Could it be that `Merk en type` is nested within another tag, for example it could be a `p` inside a `div`? Can you check the size of `output_fields` and also for each `output_field`?

Comment: I don't think it is in a `p` tag, and the size of `output_fields` is 20, 12 of them have the data I am looking for and the other 8 are just input fields I use to get the data I need printed. I made sure the input tags I need are also included in the list. I can also send you the link if you want to try as well.

Comment: Link: https://www.mobilit.fgov.be/WebdivPub/wmvpstv1 and put `WAUZZZ8VXE1009546` into `Chassisnummer` then press `Opvragen`

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't know the input formula,but I can get the field text already
u need to switch to the 
try this enjoy~

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
class roomnumber: 
    def __init__(self,url,selepath='chromedriver.exe'):
        self.url=url

        
        self.seleniumpath=selepath
        ser = Service(self.seleniumpath)
        #self.keyword=keyw
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(service = ser)
        #self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def getspon(self):
        
        
        self.driver.switch_to.frame("AppWindow")
        
        calltheporn=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="Writable3"]')
        calltheporn.send_keys('1321434534')
        
        drinksoup=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="btnOphalen"]')
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",drinksoup)
        
        
    def totheroomgettheporn(self):
        print('oh no!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        self.driver.close()
        
    

x=roomnumber('https://www.mobilit.fgov.be/WebdivPub/wmvpstv1?SUBSESSIONID=1964746')
x.ddget()
x.getspon()
x.totheroomgettheporn()
```